# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \cdot \frac12Ce^{-C|x|}\,dx$ where C is a constant

Tags: calculus

So I first moved the $\frac12C$ in front of the integral and then broke the integral into two halves, from negative infinity to $0$ and from $0$ to infinity. Then I realized the integral from negative infinity to $0$ is just zero.

So now trying to do the $\int \frac12C \cdot x^2e^{-Cx}\,dx$ and I am getting really strange answers. Help!

Comment: If you are going to keep asking these integral questions, you really should learn how to format them properly in LaTeX. <http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference>

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Comment: Did you not learn anything from your previous question?

Comment: I did learn from my previous problem, dustin. I was able to break the integral into two parts and solve each part, but on the second half evaluating the integral from 0 to infinity, I am getting that the integral is zero, when it should be 2C^-2

Comment: It is not possible for the integral from minus infinity to zero to be zero, since the integrand is positive. In fact, since the integrand is an even function, the integration for negative $x$ equals that for positive $x$. Look at that again.

Comment: Maybe you should show your work.

Comment: Here is my work, maybe this can show my errors:

Comment: All I see is the problem statement.

Comment: The integrand is even, so the integrals from $-\infty$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $\infty$ will be the same (provided they converge).  The integral you are trying to do now should be an easy integration by parts, if you want anyone to give you more advice I think you will need to post your working.

Comment: I used integration by parts and let u= {x^2} so du = 2xdx  Then dv = {e^-Cx}dx so v = {-1/C}{e^-Cx}  Then using the formula, I have {-x^2e^(-Cx)/C} + {2/C}$\int{xe^(-Cx)}dx$ and then did integration by parts again with u = x du = dx dv = e^(-cx)          v = {-1/C}e^(-Cx)

Comment: then after applying the formula again and doing integration one more time I ended up with (-x^2e^-Cx)/C - (2x/C^2)e^(-Cx) - (1/C^2)e^(-Cx) evaluated from o to infinity

Comment: It's very hard to read that comment but I think you have a sign error in the last term.

Comment: Put all that in the post not the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Your two halves should in fact be equal to each other, since this is an even function.  In other words
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\cdot \frac 1 2 C e^{-C|x|}\, dx = \int_0^\infty Cx^2 e^{-Cx}\,dx.
$$
This is
$$
\frac 1 {C^2} \int_0^\infty (Cx)^2 e^{-Cx} (C\, dx) = \frac 1 {C^2} \int_0^\infty u^2 e^{-u}\,du.
$$

Do you know that $\displaystyle n!=\int_0^\infty w^n e^{-w}\,dw$?